# slideToggle for a table row

Tags: javascript, jquery

According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9931057/jquery-slidetoggle-not-smooth) the sliding effect does now work well with tables.  I'm trying to figure out a way to implement the slideToggle feature into the code below.

The code below is properly removing/showing the designated contents, but it is not doing it with the slide motion.

The [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v4msV/) located in the above post solved their situation by putting a `div` within the `td`, so for my situation I attempted to put a `div` inside the `<tr>` to solve my situation, but it wasn't working.

```js
$(".one").on('click', function() {
    $(this).nextAll('.two:first').slideToggle(); 
});
```

```css
.one{
    background: orange;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.two{
    background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tr class="one">
        <td> Hello </td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
        <td> world </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="two">
        <td> Foo <br> foo </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="two">
        <td> Bazz </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="one">
        <td> Hello </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="two">
        <td> Bar<br>bar </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to slideToggle table row using Jquery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1112726/how-to-slidetoggle-table-row-using-jquery)

Comment: @Imgonzalves please post as answer so that I can give you credit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wrap the content inside `td` elements in a `div`, and then you can do:

```
$(this).nextAll('.two:first').find('div').slideToggle();
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/v4msV/29/)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you will put more columns in your code, but I'd recommend you using a < table > only when the information you want to show needs it.

For example in the code you posted here you could(should) nest it just using < div > with *display: inline-block;* and *margin: 0 auto;*

Something like:

```
<div class="one"> Hello </div>
<div class="one"> world </div>
<div class="two"> Foo <br> foo </div>
etc...
```

If you NEED to work with a table then the link posted by @SarahBourt might be your best option.